# Copy one file to multiple folders with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

Is it possible to copy one file to multiple directories with Grunt?
ie :

```
expand: true,
cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/client/*',
src: 'core/index.html'
```

Where the * is all the subfolders inside the clients folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with `*`, you have to map any folder using `files` option. You do not need the `expand` option in this case:

```
files: [
  { src: 'core/index.html' dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/folder1' },
  { src: 'core/index.html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/folder2' },
  { src: 'core/index.html' <%= yeoman.app %>: 'dest/folder3' },
]
```